# Access nested class

Tags: c#, class, nested

I want to make my code easier to use and this is what I'm trying.

```
public class Engine
{
    public class FileMgr
    {

    }

}
```

I can access this like Engine.FileMgr thats ok but.

I want my classes in seperated files so i want it like this

```
public class Engine
{
  public static FileMgr fileMgr;

}

public class FileMgr
{

}
```

But I cant access it anymore like `Engine.FileMgr`.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, but how is having to use a class name as if it were part of the namespace supposed to make things easier to read?

Comment: I don't see the point. You can just access it as `FileMgr` now, without the `Engine.` part.

Comment: @Nyerguds OP wants to access fileMgr property of type FileMgr class not the class itself ... read the question. Btw You should be able to call Enging.fileMgr but You need to instantiate it ofc !

Comment: @MajkeloDev that's not the way the question reads to me at all. Time to vote for closing it as the question is too unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent type `Engine` is now dropped from the class name of `Engine.FileMgr` since it is no longer a child class of `Engine`. That is like it is supposed to be. Simply remove `Engine.` from the type name and you are set.

If you really really really want to have the class name prefixed, use a `partial` class of `Engine` across the two files.

```
// Engine.cs
public partial class Engine
{
}

// Engine.FileMgr.cs
public partial class Engine
{
    public class FileMgr
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: because you have written more. ;)

Comment: It simply isn't possible to downvote this hack enough. You have taken an already bad idea (exposing the inner workings of a class through making a subclass public), you then you introduce the complication of an unnecessary partial class. This is bad.

Comment: I didn't propose a hack. Where did I do that? I propose to drop the type name from the class name, making the nested class not nested any more (if that is the intention of OP, it is okay, right?). If it has to remain a nested class there is nothing wrong with splitting some logic over different files, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the Engine class partial and put the FileMgr details inside of it.

```
public partial class Engine
{
    // Engine stuff here.
}

public partial class Engine
{
    public class FileMgr
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It simply isn't possible to downvote this hack enough. You have taken an already bad idea (exposing the inner workings of a class through making a subclass public), you then you introduce the complication of an unnecessary partial class. This is bad.

Comment: @DavidArno The OP didn't ask if it was good or bad. The OP asked how to do it. I showed him/her how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`Engine.fileMgr` is now is a field and no longer a type. SO you should use it like this:

```
FileMgr fm = Engine.fileMgr;
```